# App Freezes when received more than one push notifications

Tags: ios7, push-notification

Our App is not having any issue on iOS6 but on iOS7, On receiving more than one Push Notifications, App freezes and have to force closed the app.

We've implemented didReceiveRemoteNotification and show the Notification in UIAlertView and Post NSNotfication to Designated View Controller. We even tried removing NSNotification but app still got freeze.

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{ 
     UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
     if (state == UIApplicationStateActive){
         NSString *message = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"];
         [UserHelper showError:@"" withMessage:message];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotifyNotification object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
     }
}
```

This is the structure for Push Notifications

```
 {
    NewsFeedItemGUID = "6d4a3eeb-12bf-4371-896c-230b11217c52";
    "_" = OKt9EVHaEeOu3QAbIbyL6A;
    aps =     {
        alert = "a1 a1 completed the profile Affection Type Revealed in Love & Lust, Level 1";
    };
}

{
    NewsFeedItemGUID = "bcc72f7c-a9d3-4d2d-bcfe-b36573baee93";
    "_" = "OZ-hEVHaEeOOAZDiugJkgA";
    aps =     {
        alert = "a1 a1 just completed Level 1 in Love & Lust";
    };
}
```

We've compiled app with both iOS6 (XCode 4.6.2) and iOS7 (XCode7.0.1) but the issue persist. We also have not iOS7 related Push Notification Methods, Does those seems to cause the issue ? Any help, suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try commenting the whole code inside the `- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` and check if still hangs.. Also do check the 256 bytes limit of data on payload as well although it should not cause the crash

Comment: Its din't freez when i comment everything in didReceiveRemoteNotification

Comment: than APN is not an issue.. check these 2 functions `         NSString *message = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"];
         [UserHelper showError:@"" withMessage:message];`you must be doing something wrong there